# How to compare DateTimeField with Date in Django filter funtion?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

In my django app I have a MessageModel with a DateTimeField "send_date". I want to filter the messages to get all messages send a certain day (Date). How do I compare the DateTimeField with a Date to get all messages send within that day. I have try with

```
 query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date=myDate)
```

but it does not show the correct results. Here is the deffinition of the Model

```
class MessageModel(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='+', verbose_name=_('Destinatario'), editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Asunto"),max_length=50)

    send_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Fecha de envío") ,auto_now_add=True)
        
    message_body = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Mensaje"))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'riesgo_message'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = _("Mensaje")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Mensajes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions:

1. Use `date` function provided by SQL(`__date=`):

```py
query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date__date=myDate)
```

or:

```py
query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date__date="2021-06-01")
```

2. Use `__range=`:

```py
query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date__range=(myDate, myDate + timedelta(days=1)))
```

3. Use `__startswith=` or `__contains=`, similar usage to `__date=`
4. Use `__gt=` and `__lt=`, similar to `__range=`

All of the options above are supposing you're using the same timezone between the certain day and the data stored in database, if not, let's say if you saved datetime field in UTC while the timezone of your variable `myDate` is not UTC, then you probably need to convert a pair of datetime range in UTC first, and then query database by using `range` or `gt, lt` filter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you:

```
query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(<received_date/send_date>__date=datetime.date(2021,6,5))
```

should help you.

please note that you dont have that field in the model.(hence the <..>)

Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date

Answer (score 0):

1.To get results in that date:

```
query_result= MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date='2021-06-11')
```

2. To get results in a range of dates: give start date and end date

   ```
   query_result = MessageLogModel.objects.filter(received_date__range=['2021-06-01','2021-06-11'])
   ```